# Write a program that loops, reading characters from standard input and writing their decimal values to standard output one per line, until EOF occurs

Tags: c

I've tried to write a program that reads characters from the standard input inside a loop and write their decimal values to standard output one per line until `EOF` occurs.

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char c;
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF) {
        scanf("%c",&c);
        printf("%d\n",c);
    }
}
```

When enter:

```
Hi!
Line 2
```

The output should be:

```
72
105
33
10
76
105
110
101
32
50
10
```

How can I get 2 lines as input and read **Enter** as a character?

Comment: What's the value of `c` for the first tim you check it in the loop condition?

Comment: don't use `scanf()`, for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get 2 lines as input and read "Enter" as character?

Well, you are already reading the "Enter" (i.e. `\n`). In fact you are also using it to terminate the `while` loop. Therefore your program will stop after reading the first line. In other words - if you want to be able to read multiple lines remove the check for `\n` in the `while`

Also notice that your program uses `c` before it's initialize. Something which you should never do.

BTW: I think `getc` is a better function for this than `scanf`.

Something like this should do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    while((c = getc(stdin)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%d\n",c);
    }
}
```

Comment: `while((c = getc(stdin))!=EOF)` does exactly the same

Comment: some standards (MISRA for example) bare programmers from using `continue` and `break`;